# I need help to build an android NDK toolchain with gfortran

Tags: android-ndk, octave, gfortran

I have tried building an android NDK toolchain with gfortran compiler according to the Danilo' [blog](http://danilogiulianelli.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-build-gcc-fortran-cross-compiler.html).Unfortunately failed under OS Ubuntu14.04-64bits. The infomation provided by compiler is attached below. I wanna port Octave to Android(ARM) from source code and a fortran cross compiler is needed. Many thanks for any idea about the ndk with fortran or the approach of porting Octave.

Compiler Info:

```
libtool:finish:PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin:/opt/AndroidDev/standalone-r10/bin:/opt/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r8c:/opt/AndroidDev/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130917/sdk-kivy/tools:/sbin" ldconfig -n /tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/temp-install/lib
Libraries have been installed in:
   /tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/temp-install/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/mpfr-3.0.1'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/mpfr-3.0.1'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/mpfr-3.0.1'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/mpfr-3.0.1'
([ -d mpc-1.0 ] || \
      mkdir mpc-1.0) && \
    ( \
     cd mpc-1.0 ; \
     error cannot find mpc-1.0/configure \
      '--enable-initfini-array' '--disable-nls' '--prefix=/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/prefix' '--with-sysroot=/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/prefix/sysroot' '--with-binutils-version=2.22.90' '--with-mpfr-version=3.0.1' '--with-mpc-version=1.0' '--with-gmp-version=5.0.5' '--with-gcc-version=4.8.0' '--with-gdb-version=7.4.1' '--with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/prefix/include/c++/4.8.0' '--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran' '--disable-libgomp' '--disable-tls' '--disable-libitm' '--disable-libatomic' '--disable-bootstrap' '--disable-libquadmath' '--disable-libquadmath-support' '--disable-plugin' '--with-arch=armv5te' --program-transform-name='s,^,arm-linux-androideabi-,' --prefix=/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/temp-install --disable-shared --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gmp=/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/ndk-aoyama/build/toolchain/temp-install) && \
    touch stmp-config-host-mpc
/bin/sh: 5: error: not found
make: *** [stmp-config-host-mpc] Error 127
  [1]: http://danilogiulianelli.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-build-gcc-fortran-cross-compiler.html
```

Sorry for the awkward edit and any suggestion will be appreciated sincerely.

Comment: have you looked into the current [octave in the app store)[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.octave]? It was prepared by Corbin Champion who made the scripts and build instructions required to do it public. See the [Android](http://wiki.octave.org/Android) on the octave wiki page for details.

Comment: Thank u for the comment. Corbin do a perfect work while what I need is main libs of Octave for Android so that I can invoke M-files in a ndk based program. I have tried downloading the Octace and its dependent debs from ARM Debian using corbin's script. Then linked a c++ object file with these libs. Unfortunately...

Comment: I was told that some undefined references occured. So I want to try building Octave manually which a toolchain with gfortran is needed.